# matplotlib.pyplot plot x-axis ticks in equal range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a sequence of y values against a sequence of x values. The x values varies in a very large range. pyplot seems using a linear x-axis. So the following code gives me a bad figure.

```
def bad_plot():
    x=[1,2,10,100,1000]
    y=[5,10,6,7,9]
    plt.plot(x,y,'rs')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

The first three points (1,5), (2,10), (10,6) are so close. I want the x-axis only have 5 ticks [1,2,10,100,100] and they are **uniformly scattered in the x-axis**. How can I achieve that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you looking for log-scaling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the record, I think this is a bad design choice for a graphic. Having non-regular (be them linear or log) ticks at regular intervals is confusing to the reader.**

Okay what you simply have to do is plot against `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` but then set the ticks to be your values of `x` at the same position using [`plt.xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,10,100,1000]
y=[5,10,6,7,9]

N = len(x)
x2 = np.arange(N)

plt.plot(x2, y)

plt.xticks(x2, x)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks. I agree your comment about confusion. In my use-case for now, the X-axis are just vary too much. For example, from [0,5,10,15,....100, 200, 300, 500, 1000,1500,...10000,20000,30000]. I tried to split the x-axis and plot into several figures. But then was asked to put in one figure.

Comment: @Peng yeah that's fair enough, I'd suggest that if you have some form of caption with the figure that you draw attention to it though maybe?

Comment: I would make that caveat much much larger and put it at the top.  @PengZhang from your description I would go with either log-scale or a broken axis.  What you are asking for is very mis-leading.

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks. I will make the description less misleading. I am quite new to plot figures. Maybe I don't even use the write terminology in desription. Could you show me how to use broken axis? I used to split it into several figures, each figure with reasonable x range.